# ¿ Cómo crear animación, uno para cada lado?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Estoy tratando de que pasen las figuras de la imagen por la pantalla cada cierto tiempo y uno hacia la izquierda y otro hacia la derecha. Por más que le doy vueltas no consigo, o se quedan estáticos, se esconden por la izquierda, etc.

He probado añadiendo lo siguiente sin éxito:

```
    @-webkit-keyframes movimiento-diagonal {
        from {
            right: -100px;
        }

        to {
            right: 1400px;
        }
    }
```

Para que salgan no tan rápido y lo hagan de vez en cuando, lo hice disminuyendo

```
from {
    left: -100px;
}
```

y aumentando

```
to {
    left: 1400px;
}
```

No se si habrá alguna manera mejor sin usar JavaScript, o si hubiera que usarlo, a poner un tiempo determinado para que salgan me refiero.

*EDITO* Mi idea era que una imagen fuera hacia la derecha y otra hacia la izquierda, marchando las imágenes hacia delante y nunca hacia atrás( de espaldas).Podía tener la opción de que pasaran por la misma franja o línea o que cada una fuera por una diferente. Y siempre hacia delante.

```css
body {
  background: green;
}

@-webkit-keyframes movimiento-diagonal {
  from {
    left: -100px;
  }
  to {
    left: 1250px;
  }
}

#derecha {
  -webkit-animation-name: movimiento-diagonal;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 4s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
  /*para que vuelva a su posicion inicial */
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-image: image("../img/segadon.png");
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
}

#izquierda {
  -webkit-animation-name: movimiento-diagonal;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 4s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
  /*para que vuelva a su posicion inicial */
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-image: image("../img/segadon.png");
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="derecha">
  <img src="http://i66.tinypic.com/35n96o2.png">
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div id="izquierda">
  <img src="http://i64.tinypic.com/2ia7hbr.png">
</div>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Si lo que quieres es que las imágenes vayan en direcciones opuestas, lo que puedes hacer es darle un retraso a una de ellas. Si ese retraso es negativo, entonces  en lugar de retrasarse el inicio, lo que se hace es colocar la animación donde debería estar X tiempo antes.

He cambiado algo más el código para que siempre miren hacia adelante: añadí pasos adicionales en la animación CSS, cambie la imagen para que fuera la misma en las dos, hice que como parte de la animación la imagen se gire (fuera de pantalla). No me termina de convencer el resultado pero parece que funciona.

Algo como esto:

```css
body {
  background: green;
  overflow: hidden;
}

@-webkit-keyframes movimiento-diagonal {
  0% {
    left: -100px;
    transform: scaleX(-1);
  }
  50% {
    left: calc(100% + 100px);
    transform: scaleX(-1);
  }
  50.000001% {
    left: calc(100% + 100px);
    transform: scaleX(1) translateY(100px);
  }
  100% {
    left: -100px;
    transform: scaleX(1) translateY(100px);
  }
}

#derecha {
  -webkit-animation-name: movimiento-diagonal;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 8s;
  -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  -webkit-animation-timing-function: linear;
  /*para que vuelva a su posicion inicial */
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  background-image: image("../img/segadon.png");
  color: #fff;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="derecha">
  <img src="http://i66.tinypic.com/2ia7hbr.png">
</div>
```

Antes tenías la animación con un `to` y `from`, eso es equivalente al estado inicial y final, pero las animaciones en CSS permiten describir porcentajes (`from` equivaldría a 0% y `to` al 100%). Entonces lo que he hecho es añadir dos estados más a la animación, aquí describo lo que hacen paso a paso:

- 0%: el estado inicial. El hombrecito apunta hacia la derecha y está colocado en la izquierda, fuera de la vista. Estos son los valores por defecto (`scaleX` para que no haya cambio de dirección.)
- 50%: el hombrecito está a la derecha, fuera de la vista y todavía mirando a la derecha.
- 50.0000001%: (esto es muy cutre lo sé, en otras ocasiones he usado `step-end` para evitar esto pero no lo he conseguido en esta). El hombrecito sigue a la derecha fuera de la vista, pero ahora le hemos hecho girar para que mire a la izquierda (cambiando el `scaleX` de valor) y lo hemos bajado un poco (con el `translateY`).
- 100%: estado final. El hombrecito apunta hacia la izquierda y está colocado en la izquierda, fuera de la pantalla.

Y ahora el navegador se encarga de transicionar entre estados (con el valor de 8 segundos que le puse) y repetirse infinitamente (como ya le tenías puesto). Da la impresión de ser el mismo personaje moviéndose de derecha a izquierda una y otra vez... porque de hecho es el mismo personaje haciendo eso :)

Comment: Gracias de nuevo @Alvaro Montoro, la cosa es que no quería que las imágenes fueran de espaldas, por eso puse dos, una mirando a la derecha y otra mirando a la izquierda. Quería que fueran hacia los dos lados pero mirando siempre hacia delante. Y no se si por la misma linea seria mucha dificultad. Quizá deba editar la pregunta..

Comment: ok @MiguelEspeso. Voy a cambiar el código para que haga eso, pero debes editar tu pregunta para indicar eso. No queda claro tal y como está escrito.

Comment: @MiguelEspeso edite la respuesta, dime si eso es más o menos lo que buscabas

Comment: @AlvaroMontoro buen truco :) . +1

Comment: Perfecto @AlvaroMontoro . Solo una cosa que olvide al editar, ¿ seria posible que no se cruzan en pantalla? Como digo, a si podría valer pero me creo que quedaria mejor si no se cruzaran... Gracias

Comment: @MiguelEspeso ¿para que parezca una sola persona en lugar de dos?

Comment: Esa es la idea...

Comment: @MiguelEspeso voy a editar la respuesta cuando me monte en el autobús. Pero debes añadir esa información en la pregunta. Este es un ejemplo de cómo estábamos intentando resolver un problema completamente diferente en la pregunta inicial al que se ha ido desarrollando conforme proporcionabas información nueva.

Comment: Ok, ahora edito. Quizá si quito uno de las figuras podría valer, porque se puede apreciar que las dos figuras  van siempre de frente. O dejarlas y darles mas tiempo... Voy a experimentar Gracias @AlvaroMontoro

Comment: @MiguelEspeso Ya he hecho el cambio. He eliminado una de las figuras y le he añadido una traslación vertical para que aparezca más abajo cuando vuelve.

Comment: Muchas gracias, @AlvaroMontoro,  me a costado pillar el primer truco, el de las misma imagen para los dos lados....

Comment: Perdón por la confusión. Editaré la pregunta para explicar de manera más detallada qué es lo que ocurre

Answer (score 6):

Según lo que entiendo *(me arriesgo a que no sea lo que desea)*  , deseas que se vayan de un lado a otro, en lugar de utilizar `pixeles` puede utilizar `porcentajes` `%` , además puede crear dos animaciones uno para que vaya de izquierda a derecha y otro caso contrario.

```css
body{ background: green;}
@-webkit-keyframes movimiento-diagonal-izquierda {
    from {left: -10% }
    to { left: 100%;  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes movimiento-diagonal-derecha {
    from {left: 100% }
    to { left: -10% ; }
}

#derecha {
    -webkit-animation-name: movimiento-diagonal-izquierda;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 4s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
     -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
}


#izquierda {
    -webkit-animation-name: movimiento-diagonal-derecha;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 4s;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
     -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    color: #fff;
    position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div id="derecha">
    <img src="http://i66.tinypic.com/35n96o2.png">
</div>
<div id="izquierda">
  <img src="http://i64.tinypic.com/2ia7hbr.png">
</div>
```

Comment: Si, quiza no me explique bien @Dev. Joel quiero que vayan una para cada lado, no cruzándose y que no vayan las imágenes hacia atrás, por eso puse dos diferentes, una mira para cada lado.  Osea, uno vaya a la derecha y el otro a la izquierda. Gracias.

Comment: @MiguelEspeso sí, entendí mal su pregunta.

Comment: El erro fue mio @Dev. Joel , de echo tube que editar la pregunta, perdona. y gracias por el apoyo.

Answer (score 4):

Una solución es que crees dos animaciones con los datos contrarios, así siempre podrás manipular cada una como quieres.

Para que parezca que solo son una por cada dirección puedes usar un atraso como indico el usuario anterior.

Y para voltear la dirección de la imagen, teniendo una sola, usa escalar solo en X y en negativo y verás como sale al contrario, ejemplo: `transform: scaleX(-1)`

Ahora en cuanto a la distancia, yo te recomiendo usar mejor las medidas relativas al viewport `vw` y `vh`, ya que es más fácil hacer calculos así, por ejemplo si quieres que se desplace a más de la mitad de la ventana en el eje X: `150vw` y a menos de la mitad de la ventana a la izquierda: `-50vw`.

```css
body{
  background: green;
  margin: 0;
}

.animation-container{
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 100vw;
  background: cyan;
}

.objeto{
  animation: linear 6s infinite both;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
}

.objeto img{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

#izquierda{
  animation-name: izquierda;
  margin-top: 5em;
}

#derecha {
  animation-name: derecha;
  animation-delay: 1.5s;
}

@keyframes izquierda {
  0%{    
    transform: translateX(-50vw) scaleX(-1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(150vw) scaleX(-1);
  }
  51%{
    transform: translateX(150vw) scaleX(1);
  }
  100%{  
    transform: translateX(-50vw) scaleX(1);
  }
}

@keyframes derecha {
  0%{    
    transform: translateX(150vw) scaleX(-1);
  }
  50% {
    transform: translateX(-50vw) scaleX(-1);
  }
  51%{
    transform: translateX(-50vw) scaleX(1);
  }
  100%{  
    transform: translateX(150vw) scaleX(1);
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="animation-container">
  <div class="objeto" id="derecha">
    <img src="http://i66.tinypic.com/35n96o2.png">
  </div>
  <div class="objeto" id="izquierda">
    <img src="http://i64.tinypic.com/2ia7hbr.png">
  </div>
</section>
```

Cómo viendo que ya te respondieron muy bien a la pregunta, agrego lo siguiente, si lo quieres es usar solo una animación y controlar la dirección o escala de una manera más cómoda puedes usar las variables, ejemplo:

```css
body{
  background: green;
  margin: 0;
}

.animation-container{
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 100vw;
  background: cyan;
}

.objeto{
  animation: animacion linear 6s infinite both;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  position: relative;
  --ladoA: scaleX(-1);
  --ladoB: scaleX(1);
}

.objeto img{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

#izquierda{
  margin-top: 5em;
  --direccion1: translateX(-50vw);
  --direccion2: translateX(150vw);
}

#derecha {
  animation-delay: 1.5s;
  --direccion1: translateX(150vw);
  --direccion2: translateX(-50vw);
}

@keyframes animacion {
  0%{    
    transform: var(--direccion1) var(--ladoA);
  }
  45% {
    transform: var(--direccion2) var(--ladoA);
  }
  55%{
    transform: var(--direccion2) var(--ladoB);
  }
  95%, 100%{  
    transform: var(--direccion1) var(--ladoB);
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="animation-container">
  <div class="objeto" id="derecha">
    <img src="http://i66.tinypic.com/35n96o2.png">
  </div>
  <div class="objeto" id="izquierda">
    <img src="http://i64.tinypic.com/2ia7hbr.png">
  </div>
</section>
```

Y con una sola animación declarada, puedes manipular usando distintas clases la -`--distancia-inicial:`, la `--distancia-final`. Incluso la escala, como hice yo.

### Actualización

También vi, que en realidad se puede hacer con una sola imagen, pues usando en variables también es fácil de lograr, solo debes crear otra variable para la altura como por ejemplo `--altura1` y `--altura2`, y si quieres que esta segunda lo que haga es que "la venida" sea al borde del contenedor de la animación, pues esta también la puedes volver una variable, digamos `--y:` y a este le restas la medida de alto que tenga la imagen, digamos `--x`. En fin, no hay nada mejor que un ejemplo visual:

```css
body{
  background: green;
  margin: 0;
}

.animation-container{
  overflow: hidden;
  max-width: 100vw;
  background: cyan;
  --y: 120px;
  min-height: var(--y);
}

.objeto{
  animation: animacion linear 6s infinite both;
  --x: 40px;
  width: var(--x);
  height: var(--x);
  position: relative;
  --ladoA: scaleX(1);
  --ladoB: scaleX(-1);
  --direccion1: translateX(-50vw);
  --direccion2: translateX(150vw);  
  --altura1: translateY(0); 
  --posicion2: calc( var(--y) - var(--x) );
  --altura2: translateY( var(--posicion2));
}

.objeto img{
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

@keyframes animacion {
  0%{    
    transform: var(--altura1) var(--direccion1) var(--ladoA);
  }
  45% {
    transform: var(--altura1) var(--direccion2) var(--ladoA);
  }
  55%{
    transform: var(--altura2) var(--direccion2) var(--ladoB);
  }
  95%, 100%{ 
    transform: var(--altura2) var(--direccion1) var(--ladoB);
  }
}
```

```html
<section class="animation-container">
  <div class="objeto">
    <img src="http://i66.tinypic.com/35n96o2.png">
  </div>
</section>
```

Aunque también se puede lograr perfectamente sin variables, es más dinámico, ya que solo tendrías que cambiar la medida del alto del contenedor y la altura y ancho de la imagen y todo lo demás se calcula solo. Éxitos!

Comment: Gracias @Edgar Gutiérrez , me apunto tu propuesta que es muy buena. Ya le di por buena la respuesta al compañero Alvaro, pero me copio tu respuesta. Muchas gracias, es que Alvaro estuvo muy ágil, lo soluciono increíblemente, teniendo en cuenta que edite la pregunta. Un saludo compañero.

Comment: Claro, esa es la idea! Éxitos!, por cierto la edite otra vez para lograrlo con una sola imagen también.

Comment: Gracias, ya vere cual se acopla mejor al código cuando monte todo, pues quiero que las imágenes pasen sobre los elementos de la pagina que estoy creando. Espero que sea posible.